# How can disallow su -

Tags: sudo, su

I am a system administrator and I do not want users to use `su - $appuser` and try entering the password of the app user

rather

use `sudo su - $appuser` and enter their own password.

Some naïve users who are not aware try to do `su - $appuser` and enter an incorrect password, by doing this the application user gets locked after 3 unsuccessful attempts (defined by the AD team; cannot be changed). We want to force users to use `sudo su -`

Can this be achieved ?

Comment: Which OS is this?

Comment: Why `sudo su`? It's a horrible construct and totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you could always use the traditional BSD-route...

Create a group - **wheel** is the traditional name...

Add users allowed to use `su` into this group - in your case, none (maybe except **root**, but **root** is allowed anyway).

Set the group-ownership of `su` to **wheel**

Take away *others* execution-rights for `su`

By the end, `su` should have **root:wheel** ownership, and it's permission should be: rws--x---  (ie. `chmod u=rwxs,g=x,o= su`) (or even better; --s--x--- ; ie. `chmod u=xs,g=x,o= su`)

This will prevent anybody but **root** and members of **wheel** from executing `su`.  Since using `sudo` effectively makes any user **root**, `sudo su ...` should also work.

Comment: There isn't really much gained from removing a+r on `/bin/su`. At least if it's the one your distro ships—anyone can just download it from the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a system that uses PAM (e.g., almost all Linux systems), then you have a few more options.

1. Edit `/etc/pam.d/su` and add a line like `su      auth     required       pam_wheel.so` before your LDAP/AD/etc. authentication. This gives you the `wheel` group, through PAM instead of file ownership. You can also do much more flexible things using `pam_succeed_if`.
2. Edit the same, and either change `auth sufficient pam_rootok.so` (which lets root use `su`) to `auth required pam_rootok.so` (to let *only* root use `su`), or alternatively put `auth required pam_deny.so` at some point.
3. Same file, you could do something like `auth required pam_succeed_if.so uid ne $appuser` to just block `su` to the app user.

I apologize in advance I haven't tested any of those.